# Бот, работающий с csv файлами, можно ли?

Tags: python, файлы, машинное-обучение, csv, бот

Недавно написала бота-болталку и задалась вопросом. Можно ли создать бота, который принимал на вход csv файл(к примеру, с учениками, предметами и их успеваемостью), обрабатывал это и выдавал статистику по требуемым предметам. К примеру, я пишу "Алгебра" и бот дает статистику по успеваемости класса по этому предмету? Сама я новичок в программировании, поэтому сразу хочу узнать выполнимо это или нет, чтобы прилагать усилия с умом.  Бота хочу реализовывать в Телеге, реализация идеи на Питоне.
Всем заранее спасибо)

Comment: наверное машинное обучение тут будет излишним. успеваемость это средняя оценка ? её можно и так расчитать

Comment: Да, но имеется в виду именно бот, который бы ускорял учительскую работу в разы. Скидываете файл, пару секунд и статистика на "столе".Условно.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы можете реализовать вашу задумку на Python.

Для **Парсинга** (*преобразование текста в удобный для работы в коде формат*) CSV-строки вы можете использовать встроенный в Python модуль под названием `csv`.

Документацию и примеры скриптов с использованием модуля **csv** вы можете посмотреть [по этой ссылке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо!)